# osgText with getBound()

Tags: openscenegraph

Is it possible to do a getBound() on osgText without setting its position before that i.e.

```
osg::ref_ptr<osgText::Text> label = new osgText::Text;
geode->addDrawable( label.get() );
label->setText("Event: 
dist = label->getBound().xMax();
```

and somewhere later after deciding on the position i would do this

```
label->setPosition(pos);
```

The problem i am facing right now is that getBound() seems to return diff values with GL and GLES builds.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't set the bounding volume OSG will return the default BoundingBox parameters (xmax, xmin, etc). The default BoundingBox will depend on your GL build.

Ideally getBound() will return the bounds of nodes once you set them.

Comment: Would you please clarify "once you set them"?  Do you have to do a cull or draw pass on the text node to set the bounds?